# Rails, MySql, JSON column which stores array of UUIDs - Need to do exact match

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model called lists, which has a column called `item_ids`. `item_ids` is a JSON column (MySQL) and the column contains array of UUIDs, each referring to one item.

Now when someone creates a new list, I need to search whether there is an existing list with same set of UUIDs, and I want to do this search using query itself for faster response. Also use ActiveRecord querying as much as possible.

How do i achieve this?

```
item_ids = ["11E85378-CFE8-39F8-89DC-7086913CFD4B", "11E85354-304C-0664-9E81-0A281BE2CA42"]

v = List.new(item_ids: item_ids)
v.save!
```

Now, how do I check whether a list exists which has item ids exactly matches with that mentioned in query ? Following wont work.

```
list_count = List.where(item_ids: item_ids).count
```

**Edit 1**

```
List.where("JSON_CONTAINS(item_ids, ?) ", item_ids.to_json).count
```

This statement works, but it counts even if only one of the item matches. Looking for exact number of items.

**Edit 2**

```
List.where("JSON_CONTAINS( item_ids, ?) and JSON_LENGTH(item_ids) = ?", item_ids.to_json, item_ids.size).count
```

Looks like this is working

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a has many relation between lists and items and then access like this.

> List.includes(:item).where('items.id in (?)',item_ids)

To implement has_many relation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association